# "S->value <= 0" signal() implementation in semaphore with no busy waiting

Tags: synchronization, signals, semaphore

following is the code of `signal()` operation in semaphore with no busy waiting (without busy waiting)

Implementation of `signal()`:

```
signal (semaphore *S) {
    S->value++; 
    if (S->value <= 0) { 
        remove a process P from S->list; 
        wakeup(P);  
    } 
}
```

and i have a question with "if-condition".

i think, the fact that `S->value` is zero or negative means that there is no available resource, so `wakeup()` should not be permitted.
but as you can see, whenever `signal()` operation is called, a process (which is in waiting list) is being woken regardless of the state of `S->value`.

so in my opinion,
a sign of inequality `S->value >= 0` is natural and makes sense, because `S->value > 0` means there are available resoures.

is there anybody who can explain to me in easy english?

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing between Semaphore's queue and the ready queue here.
This solution is to meet the bounded waiting condition.

When a process must wait for a semaphore S, it is blocked and put on the semaphore’s queue.
signal() removes one process from the queue and moves it to Ready queue.
Because signal() is always called from a process which has just finished its critical section. So there will be a new process added to the ready queue.

If you add a process to the ready queue when semaphore's value is positive it doesn't make sense because you can use the semaphore directly then and there, without joining the ready queue.

```
    signal (semaphore *S) {
        S->value++; 
        if (S->value <= 0) { 
        remove a process P from S->list; 
        wakeup(P);  //move one process P from S->list to ready list
        } 
    }
```

The negative value indicates a number of processes waiting.
Hope this helps.